# Counting Rule Problem

Tags: combinatorics

I want to ask a combinatorics question...

*If the question is a simple one, i.e.,*
If I have 2 T-shirts and 2 pants for my 2 kids (assume they are the same size), where pant is worn after the T-shirt, then there are how many ways to put on the T-shirts and pants for my kids?

It still can be done by listing method, i.e.,
let s1 be the shirt worn by kid 1, s2 be the shirt worn by kid 2, p1 be the pant worn by kid 1, and p2 be the pant worn by kid 2.

1. s1, p1, s2, p2
2. s2, p2, s1, p1
3. s1, s2, p1, p2
4. s1, s2, p2, p1
5. s2, s1, p1, p2
6. s2, s1, p2, p1

*However, if the question becomes complicated. For instance,*
If I have 5 T-shirts and 5 pants for my 5 kids (assume they are the same size), where pant is worn after the T-shirt, then there are how many ways to put on the T-shirts and pants for my kids?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts. Note:  it's not clear (to me) how the order of putting on clothes matters here.

Comment: Are they all the same size?  What are your thoughts?